# PHP, HTML code review

Tags: php, html

I am working on a project called online Test, where users can take the test. I have created a php code in the following format but its hard coded. Below is the code. If I click on C it will take me to c test and similarly c++

```
<center><h2><b>Select the test</b></h2>
<a href="promo.php?course=c"><div class="test"><b>C</b></a></div><br>
<a href="promo.php?course=c++"><div class="test"><b>C++</b></a></div><br>
</center>
```

Now the question is I want to make this page has dynamic. To fetch all the course that are there in the database and if user selects a particular test, he should get the test for that particular subject.

```
<form action="promo.php" method="post">
<h2><center>
   <td><select name="links"  id="links" value=' ' ">
<?php  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($out))
{

echo "<option value=" .$row['course_id']." > ". $row['c_name']." </option>"; 

}
?>
</select>

<input type="Submit" value="Start" /></center>
</form>
```

This is what I have done, it displays all the courses in the drop down fetching from the database. When I click the start button, it does not start any test because promo.php requires another parameter.
I am not able to send the course name along with the promo.php. How to do this
Can any one help me with this code

Comment: Elaborate your problem. You need to send Course name along with the course id. Is that what you are asking? You have a stray `"` in the `select` tag btw.

Comment: Change the `form method` to `get` and the `select name` to `course`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some points is not cleared but I assume you can do like this :

Change select box name to `name="course"`

```
<select name="course"  id="course">
```

And if you want to send a select box value to a page like this : `promo.php?course=c` then you should do `method = "get"` :

```
    <form action="promo.php" method="get">

<h2><center>

<select name="course"  id="course">

    <?php  
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($out))
    {

    echo '<option value="'.$row['c_name'].'" > '.$row['c_name'].' </option>'; 

    }
    ?>

</select>

<input type="Submit" value="Start" /></center>
</form>
```

Comment: I changed my code as you said, still it's not working. Now its not taking me to next page i.e promo.php

Comment: did you copied all code between <form> ..</form> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but why not include the other parameter in your form? Just add another `<input type="text">`, `<select>` or `<input type="hidden">`, as appropriate.